# Angular is substracting 1 day from calendar component

Tags: javascript, java, angular, primeng

I have a date form component from PrimeNg, whenever i submit my form it substracts 1 day:
[image]

i get this in my API

```
"datePlanning": "2021-04-29"
```

in the **backend** it's declared

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date datePlanning;
```

in the **frontend** it's decalred as a Date
and in the formBuilder:

```
datePlanning: [this.selectedData.datePlanning],
```

Comment: @deHaar i made  a little mistake; in the frontend i set the date as "2021-07-25" in the API i get "2021-07-24"

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i made a little mistake; in the frontend i set the date as "2021-07-25" in the API i get "2021-07-24"

Comment: My guess is that the UI uses a date formatter to generate a date string but uses the wrong time zone

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: SOLVED**
Primeng calendar has a property "dataType" ."DataType" is "date" in default. If you set "string" instead of "date", then it's working perfectly and sending correct date to server.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p-calendar dataType="string"></p-calendar>
```

setting property "datetype" as "string" will resolve this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).